# Cannot Close jQuery UI Dialog Box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Here is the jquery for the code to open/close the dialog and the HTML links:

```
$("#security-code-link").click(function() {
    $("#security-code-box").dialog({ 
        draggable: false, 
        height: 500,
        modal: true,
        position: ["center","center"], 
        resizable: false, 
        width: 500
    });
});

$("#close-security-code-link").click(function() {
        $("#security-code-box").dialog("close");
});


<a id="security-code-link">Where is this?</a>
<div id="security-code-box">
<h3>Where is my security code?</h3>
<div class="center">
    <img src="<?php bloginfo("template_directory"); ?>/images/security-codes.jpg" />
    <br /><a id="close-security-code-link">Close this box</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Why is the dialog box not closing?

Comment: Its working for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/G9GY8/2/

using ff4, what browser are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#security-code-box").dialog({ 
        draggable: false, 
        height: 500,
        modal: true,
        position: ["center","center"], 
        resizable: false, 
        width: 500,
        autoOpen: false
    });
    $("#security-code-link").live('click', function() {
       $("#security-code-box").dialog('open');
    });
    $("#close-security-code-link").live('click', function() {
       $("#security-code-box").dialog("close");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/muF8S/1/

Make sure your script is within your ready function.